# Example of a subgroup for normality

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Give an example of a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$, such that *for  some* $g\in G,\     g^{-1}Hg\subset H$ *i.e.* $g^{-1}Hg$  is properly contained in $H$.

Comment: Do you know how to accept answers to your questions? I suggest you read up on it, as it's generally considered a good idea.

Comment: ok !!Sir...I edited this....

Comment: If you really mean *properly* contained, that is $g^{-1}H g\subset H$ does not allow the case $g^{-1}H g= H$, then no such example exists as the condition fails for $g=1$. Without "properly", any normal subgroup will do.

Comment: No such example exists, as $g^{-1}Hg \subseteq H$ implies (by applying $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$) $H \subseteq gHg^{-1}$ and hence: If $g^{-1}Hg \subset H$ for all $g$, then $H \subset gHg^{-1}$ for all $g$. Impossible.

Comment: Sir, Is it true for some g belong G.

Comment: Plz see the edited problem.

Comment: yes sir !! plz help

Comment: @ram: What people are trying to tell you is that you so far have asked 5 questions, but you haven't **accepted** any of the answers that have been given. If you expect someone to answer this question, then you should (1) read http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask, (2) go back an accept answers to your other questions.

Comment: I just found out that this question is an exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/, itself being closed as an exact (though not really) duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613 (I suppose, how can I be sure?). Now already having given an answer below, can I in all decency vote to close this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be the set of affine transformations of $\mathbb R$. That is, $G=\{x\mapsto a x + b: a,b\in{\mathbb R}, a\neq 0\}$. Let $H\subset G$ be the subgroup of integer shifts, $H = \{x\mapsto x+k:k\in {\mathbb Z}\}$, and $g(x) = x/2$. Consider $h\in H$. Let $h(x) = x + k$. Then
$$g^{-1}hg(x) = 2 \cdot (x/2 + k) = x + 2k.$$
That is, $g^{-1}hg$ lies in the subgroup of shifts by an even integer number, $H_2 = \{x\mapsto x+2k:k\in {\mathbb Z}\}$, which is properly contained in $H$.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly an example of a subgroup strictly containing a conjugate of it requires an infinite group. The following example is rather large, but easy to understand; maybe there are more elementary examples.

Let $\Gamma$ be the oriented graph on $\mathbf Z\times\mathbf N$ where $(i,j)$ has a single outgoing edge to $(i+1,\lfloor\frac j2\rfloor)$ (so every point has $2$ incoming edges). Let $G$ be the group of automorphisms of $\Gamma$, $H$ the subgroup stabilising $(1,0)$, and $g:((i,j)\mapsto(i-1,j))\in G$. Then $gHg^{-1}$ is the stabiliser of the point $(0,0)$, which contains $H$ since $(1,0)$ is the unique point reachable by an outgoing edge from $(0,0)$. But $G$ contains elements that fix $(1,0)$ but interchange $(0,0)$ with $(0,1)$ (left as exercise), so $H$ strictly contains $gHg^{-1}$.