# $H<K<G$ and $gHg^{-1}< K$ implies $g^{-1}Hg < K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Does anyone know of a counter example or a proof of the following proposition?  If it doesn't hold in general are there any classes of groups for which it holds?

> Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite group and let $H<K<G$ with $H$ a maximal subgroup of $K.$  If $gHg^{-1}<K$ then $g^{-1}Hg<K.$

Thank you

Comment: It trivially holds for abelian groups. :)

Comment: @coffeemath I meant to include the qualifier "non-abelian"  I'll edit to update that thanks!

Comment: You don't have to edit it .. it is stated for arbitrary groups.

Comment: @doc true, but i'm only interested in non-abelian groups so I'll just throw away the trivial case

Comment: Yes, my comment was meant only as humor. There may be some reasonable cases where it works... Maybe there need to be some restrictions on how the chain of subgroups $H,K,G$ "sit inside each other".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $G=S_4$ and put $H=\{(1),(12)\}$ and $K=S_3$. Then $H$ is maximal in $K$ because of their orders being $2,6$ respectively, and $2|x|6$ has no nontrivial solutions.

Now let $g=(1432)$. Then [I'm doing compositions left-to-right] $gHg^{-1}=\{(1),(23)\}<K$, however $g^{-1}Hg=\{(1),(14)\}$ is not a subgroup (or even a subset) of $K.$

Note this could be switched around if one wants to do composition in the opposite right-to-left order.

Comment: thanks for the counter example, do you happen to have any insight into whether or not the proposition holds for $p$-groups?

Comment: Wow, counterexample? I'd better check my work!

Comment: Yep! Nice! I'll delete my "proof"

Comment: @doc i came up with many similar incorrect proofs just like the one you gave before I decided to look for counter examples :)

Comment: @mikevaiana -- I'm not expert enough on $p$- groups to look at that in general, but have been tinkering around looking for examples of dihedral groups with order a power of $2$. That would be a special class of $2$-groups, and a counterexample or proof even in that special case would interest me, at any rate.

Comment: Thanks Mike :)  I recall one of my profs in grad school saying "Research is about what you can do, not about what you can't do."  Never forgot those words ...

Comment: @coffeemath That would be interesting to me also, let me know if you find anything, especially a counter example!  Coincidentally, I looked at your profile and noticed you teach at St. John Fisher.  I was born and raised in Rochester, I'm doing my PhD now at UB

Comment: I believe I have a counterexample for a $2$-group. Where do you think I can post it?

Comment: @Doc I think it should be posted here as one of the answers to this question, since in the comments so far the desire for a p-group counterexample has been mentioned by the OP. At least I'd like to see such an example.

Comment: @Doc I would love to see a counter example for a 2-group, if you'd like to post it here as an answer that would be great! If not will you let me know where you do post it?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Mike and Coffeemath.  I posted it here.

Answer (score 3):

The result appears to be false even for $2$-groups.  Here is a counterexample.

Let $\, G\,$ be a Sylow-$2$ subgroup of $\;C_{S_8}((1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8))\;$ (i.e, the centralizer of 
$(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8)$ in the symmetric group $\,S_8\,$).

Let $\;K=\langle (1,2)\rangle \times \langle (3,4)\rangle \times\langle (5,6)\rangle$.

Let $\;H=\langle (1,2)\rangle \times \langle (3,4)\rangle$ and $g=(1,7,5,3)(2,8,6,4)$.

Then (using left-to-right notation):

$gHg^{-1}=(1,7,5,3)(2,8,6,4)(1,2)(1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8) =(3,4)$, and

$gHg^{-1}=(1,7,5,3)(2,8,6,4)(3,4)(1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8) =(5,6)$,

which establishes that $gHg^{-1}\le K$, however 
$g^{-1}Hg\not\le K$, since $$(1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8)(1,2)(1,7,5,3)(2,8,6,4) =(7,8)\not\in K.$$

Comment: wow, thanks for the counter-example!  I'm slightly surprised to see that it doesn't work for $p$-groups which seemed nice enough in some sense. If I could accept 2 answers I would.

Comment: This seems to me a variation of my approach, which is quite a bit more involved, and tricky enough to achieve a $2$-group counterexample. Likely one could similarly construct other $p$-group counterexamples this way, though the notation/choices would get even more involved. +1!

Comment: I'm a bit doubtful that a general counterexample would follow along these same lines, because unlike the case $p=2$ there is no $p$-element that interchanges two disjoint $p$-cycles. I'm not saying a counterexample can't be fashioned  for every $p$ though.  That should be our next challenge  :-)

Comment: @Doc I agree! Even just a counter example for $p=3$ would be interesting.

Comment: I was totally wrong when I doubted that my $2$-group counterexample couldn't be generalized to odd primes.  It can.  I'll post it here as an answer.

Comment: What I'd really like to do is find necessary and sufficient conditions for this problem.  I can't seem to let go of it ... lol.

Comment: Mike, Coffeemate: Necessary and sufficient conditions found!  I'll post as yet another (and my final) answer to this problem.

Comment: @Doc I agree it is hard to let go of once you start!  The motivation for my original question was to hopefully strengthen what you've done in your other answer (necessary and sufficient). See me comment there. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general counterexample for $p$-groups, $p$ any prime.

Let $\, G\,$ be a Sylow-$p$ subgroup of the centralizer in $S_{p^2}$ of the indicated fixed-point free element of order $p$:
$$\;C_{S_8}((1,2,\dots,p)(p,p+1,\dots,2p) \cdots (p^2-p+1, p^2-p+2, \dots, p^2)$$

Let $$\;K=\langle (1,2,\dots,p)\rangle \times \langle (p+1,p+2,\dots , 2p)\rangle \times \cdots \times \langle (p^2-2p+1, p^2-2p+2, \dots, p^2-p)\rangle.$$

Let $H$ be the following maximal subgroup of $K$: 
$$\;H=\langle (1,2,\dots,p)\rangle \times \langle (p+1,p+2,\dots , 2p)\rangle \times \cdots \times \langle (p^2-3p+1, p^2-3p+2, \dots, p^2-2p)\rangle.$$

Let $g=(1,p+1,\dots,p^2-p+1)(2,p+2,\dots,p^2-p+2)\cdots (p,2p,\dots,p^2)$.

Then (using left-to-right notation) $gHg^{-1}\le K$, however $$g^{-1}(1,2,\dots,p)g=(p^2-p+1, p^2-p+2,\dots,p^2)\not\le K.$$

Comment: I am thoroughly  impressed, thanks so much for the counter example for all $p-$groups!  Its nice to see your example generalized.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group (finite or infinite) with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $H$ is maximal in $G$, and $gHg^{-1}\le K$.  Then $g^{-1}Hg\le K$ if and only if either $H=g^{-1}Hg$ or  $K=g^{-1}Kg$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Obvious.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $g^{-1}Hg\le K$ and $gHg^{-1}\ne H$. Then $\langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle=K=\langle H, g^{-1}Hg\rangle$. But $K=\langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ implies that $g^{-1}Kg=g^{-1}\langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle g=\langle g^{-1}Hg,H\rangle=K$, i.e., $K=g^{-1}Kg$.

Comment: this was actually the motivation for the question!  I wanted to prove that the hypothesis I stated (without assume $g^{-1}Hg \leq K$) would imply that $g$ normalized either $H$ or $K.$  I was hoping that the assumptions would imply $g^{-1}Hg\leq K$ and thus imply (by what you've done here) that $g$ normalized $H$ or $K$ but from your nice counterexamples it turns out the situation is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Relaxing the finite condition, there exists a group $G$ with chain of subgroups $hKh^{-1}<K<h^{-1}Kh$. Which is a kinda cool counter-example (taking $H=hKh^{-1}$ and $g=h^2$). This follows quickly from the groups given as answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup) question.

For example, consider the subgroup $K=\langle a^2\rangle$ of the group $G=\langle a, t; tat^{-1}=a^2\rangle$. Then $tKt^{-1}=\langle a^4\rangle$ and $t^{-1}Kt=\langle a\rangle$, so we get the chain. In fact, this chain continues forever:
$$t^{i+1}Kt^{-(i+1)}<t^{i}Kt^{-i}<\dots<K<\langle a\rangle$$

As I mentioned above, this can be easily made into a formal counter-example by taking $H=tKt^{-1}$ and $g=t^2$. So in the above example, take $K=\langle a^2\rangle$ and $H=\langle a^4\rangle$, and then $g^{-1}Hg<K$ but $gHg^{-1}>K$.

(Note that we take $g:=t^2$ because this moves us two places along the chain, so "jumps" us to the other side of $K$ when moving up the chain. If we took $g:=t$ then we would have $g^{-1}Hg<K$ and $gHg^{-1}=K$)

Comment: It's very cool, but I'm not sure it answers the question.  Do you want $H$ as stated in the problem to be what you call $K$?  If so, what is $K$?  (Note that $H$ must be maximal in $K$.)

Comment: @Doc Sorry, I should have said that I was relaxing the "finite" condition (otherwise everything I say above is impossible). The subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ is maximal, again if $K$ itself was maximal this wouldn't work. (But I was willing to bend the assumptions, as it was interesting enough...)

Comment: Well what you have _can_ be made into a formal counterexample. Let $K=\langle a^2\rangle$ and $H=\langle a^4\rangle$, so that $H$ is maximal in $K$.  Now observe that $t^{-2}a^4t^2=a^{16}$ but $t^{2}a^4t^{-2}=a$.  Plase edit your answer accordingly so that I can upvote it.  Also you should mention that it is a counterexample for infinite groups.

Comment: It is actually useful to have a counter example in the infinite case, but I was mostly looking at finite groups so thats why I added the finite hypothesis, @Doc thanks for clarifying somethings with your comment