# Can a left coset be strictly contained in a right coset?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $x,y\in G$ be such that $xH\subseteq Hy$. Can we conclude that $xH=Hy$? this certainly holds if $H$ is finite because both sets will have the same finite cardinality. But what about the case $|H|=\infty$? I am especially interested in the case $x=y$.

**EDIT:** As Thomas Andrews pointed out in the comments, it is suffices to consider the case $x=y$, because the hypothesis $xH\subseteq Hy$ implies $x\in Hy$, hence $Hy=Hx$. And so, the question becomes:

> Can a subgroup (of a group, of course) strictly contain some of its conjugates?

Comment: Yeah, I think @KarolisJuodelė is confused.

Comment: If $x\in Hy$ then $Hy=Hx$. So you can reduce the question to $x=y$.

Comment: The question then becomes: Can $xHx^{-1}\subsetneq H$.

Comment: I think that you should remove the "**EDIT**", as with it your post is a duplicate (of, say, [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup)). Without it it is interesting :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. $xH\subsetneq Hx$ is equivalent to $xHx^{-1}\subsetneq H$, so we want to find a subgroup strictly containing one of its conjugates. This is possible with infinite groups. For instance, let $\psi$ act on $\Bbb Q$ by $x\mapsto2x$, and form the semidirect product $G=\Bbb Q\rtimes\langle\psi\rangle$. Then $\psi \Bbb Z\psi^{-1}=2\Bbb Z\subsetneq\Bbb Z$. I also gave this example over at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781605/characteristic-subgroups-phih-subseteq-h/781612#781612), and by googling "subgroup strictly contains conjugate" you can find more.

Comment: There are also lots of examples [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup) and in the questions linked therein.