# Can we define the normal set without $G$ being a group?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, terminology

Let $X$ be a set in $G$ and $G$ be a group. A normal set is a set $X$ for which $gxg⁻¹∈X$ for every $x∈X,g∈G$. It's just like the normality condition for subgroups, except that $X$ doesn't have to be a subgroup.

I hvae two **questions**:

(1) Can we define the normal set without $G$ being a group?

(2) The normal vector to a surface is a vector **perpendicular** to it. Does there is a relation between this notion and the notion of normal set?

Comment: $X$ is not just any set, it is a subset of $G$. Otherwise, $gxg^{-1}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @fkraiem: Yes, corrected.

Comment: Firstly, your definition of normality is off slightly - you also need the map $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ to be a bijection. Secondly, how are you hoping to define $g^{-1}$? (Incidentally, if you take $G$ to be a group and don't want $X$ to be a subgroup then this is a decent question with a concrete "yes" answer.)

Comment: @user1729: It is the invrse element of $g$.

Comment: Yes, but if $G$ is not a group then you cannot guarantee inverses.

Comment: @user1729: So the answer is NO. What about the second question.

Comment: @DER Why do you think that they should be connected?

Comment: @user1729: They have the same name and this is just an idea.

Comment: @DER Sorry, of course. I'll think about it.

Comment: @DER I have thought about it. I think you want to look up something called a "Lie algebra". I said earlier that the issue with the idea of a normal set is that you need inverses. So suppose you have inverses, so you also have an identity and a binary operation, but then you also want $G$ to *not* be a group. Therefore, you need the binary operation to not be associative. Lie algebras are vector spaces with an operation called a Lie bracket, and this bracket is not associative. Moreover, 3D vectors with the operation "cross product" form a Lie algebra. Score! This may be a red herring though...

Comment: (Also, I should say that in semigroup theory there are certain notions which "mimic" normality, so you get things like $ag\overline{g}b=ab$ for all $a, b\in S$. So inverses are not strictly necessary for what you are after. I just think that you perhaps need to think about your question slightly more.)

Comment: @user1729: Ok I will look for Lie Algebra.

Comment: @user1729 If $gXg^{-1}\subset X$ is true for every $g\in G$ then the map $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$
*automatically is a bijection*. Its inverse is the map $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$.

Comment: @drhab: Yes, this property is satisfied.

Comment: @drhab Touché .

Comment: @drhab That's not correct: a conjugation map can restrict to a subset (a subgroup even) and then fail to be onto. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781605/characteristic-subgroups-phih-subseteq-h/781612#781612).

Comment: OP: (1) I imagine $\forall a\in G,aX=Xa$ would work in a set $G$ equipped with a binary operation. This is equivalent to normality if $G$ is a group, but still makes sense if it isn't. (2) No, orthogonality in geometry and conjugation invariance in a symmetry group aren't related any more than any other randomly picked pair of mathematical concepts.

Comment: @seaturtles No, drhab is correct. The key point is that it holds *for all* $g\in G$. The example you give - and indeed any example - does not hold for every $g\in G$. Indeed, $gHg^{-1}<H\Rightarrow H<g^{-1}Hg$.

Comment: @user1729 Ah, thanks. I wasn't incorporating the for all.

Comment: @seaturtles Yes, I made the same mistake in my initial comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of normal subsets $X$ of group $G$ is absolutely valid. One can easily see that a subset is normal iff it is the union of *conjugacy* classes (a conjugacy class of an element $x \in G$ is the set $\{g^{-1}xg: g \in G\}$, which is the equivalence class of $x$ under the equivalence relation conjugation). Conjugacy classes are important in groups for several reasons beyond the scope of this answer. And with them, one can actually  "construct" normal sets. Observe that complements $G-N$ of normal subgroups $N$ of $G$ are normal subsets.

In a similar vein one can define the *centralizer* $C_G(X)=\{g \in G:g^{-1}xg=x$ for all $x \in X\} $ and *normalizer* of a set $X$, $N_G(X)=\{g \in G:g^{-1}Xg=X\}$.

Comment: Isn't this assuming that $G$ is a group and requiring that $X$ isn't a subgroup, which isn't what the question is about?

Comment: Yes $G$ must be a group, just to show that if so, normal sets are relevant.

Comment: @NickyHekster: Nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

A *congruence* in a monoid $M$ is an equivalence relation $\equiv$ in $M$ that is compatible with the operation of $M$:
$$
a \equiv b, a' \equiv b' \implies aa '\equiv bb'
$$
The quotient $\overline M = M\,/\equiv$ is then a monoid.

It is easy to prove that, when $G$ is a group and $\equiv$ is a congruence in $G$, the equivalence class of $1$ is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ and the equivalence classes are the cosets of $N$. Conversely, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the relation defined by $a \equiv b$ if $a^{-1}b \in N$ is a congruence relation in $G$ whose equivalence classes are the cosets of $N$.

I don't think there is much to say about congruences in a monoid in general because given a submonoid $N$ of a monoid $M$, the cosets of $N$ in $M$ are not necessarily disjoint and so do not define equivalence classes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rees_factor_semigroup