# Why can quotient groups only be defined for subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

I know that for the operation on cosets to be well-defined one requires normality. But why is it a requirement (with $G / N$) that $N$ be a subgroup or even a subset of $G$? Surely all that is required is that $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $S$ (say), of which $G$ is a subgroup of. In which case $G / N \le S/N$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/805185/589.

Comment: @lhf I don't think that's relevant to my question

Comment: @bwv869 I've editted my answer to address the subgroup part of your question more directly.

Answer (score 4):

For $G$ a group, a *congruence relation* on $G$ is an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $G$ with the property that, whenever $a \sim a'$ and $b \sim b'$, we have $ab \sim a'b'$. In other words, the group operation on $G$ is well-defined on the level of equivalence classes under $\sim$.

Fact: When $N \subset G$ is a normal subgroup, the equivalence relation induced by the partition of $G$ given by cosets of $N$ is a congruence relation. This is precisely what makes it possible to define the quotient group $G/N$.

Conversely,

**Theorem**: whenever $\sim$ is a congruence relation on $G$, the equivalence class $N := [e]_\sim$ forms a normal subgroup (where $e$ denotes the identity element of $G$), and $\sim$ is precisely the congruence relation induced by the partition of $G$ by $N$-cosets.

Therefore, the only way to take equivalence classes on $G$ in a manner that the group operation is well-defined is via the construction of a quotient group by a normal subgroup.

Proof: That $N$ is a subgroup is obvious, because if $a, b \sim e$, then $ab$ must be equivalent to $e^2 = e$. That $N$ is normal follows almost as easily; if $g \in G$ and $h \in N$, then $e = g e g^{-1} \sim g h g^{-1}$, so $ghg^{-1} \in N$.

It remains to show that $g \sim h$ if and only if $g h^{-1} \in N$. If $g \sim h$, then of course, $h^{-1} \sim h^{-1}$, so $g h^{-1} \sim h h^{-1} = e$, witnessing $gh^{-1} \in N$. Conversely, if $gh^{-1} \in N$, that means $g h^{-1} \sim e$, and multiplication on the right by $h$ gives $g \sim h$.

In answer to the question that Chill2Macht below points out I haven't addressed properly, namely why we require $N$ to be a sub*set* of $G$:

You are absolutely right! If $G$ is a subgroup of $S$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $S$, then we can define a group "$G/N$" to be the set of cosets of $N$ by elements of $G$, i.e., $\{gN \mid g \in G\}$. As you can infer by the scare quotes, this is not standard terminology.

Since the $gN$ determine a congruence relation on $G$, it follows from the above theorem that the group "$G/N$" is a quotient of $G$ by a *normal subgroup* of $G$, but we can be much more precise.

We have the following facts:

- The set $$GN = \bigcup_{g \in G} gN = \{gn \mid g \in G, n \in N\}$$ is a subgroup of $S$.
- $N$ is a normal subgroup of $GN$, so that $GN/N$ is defined (standard terminology). Moreover, we have $GN/N = $ "$G/N$", both as a set and as a group.
- Finally, $N \cap G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and there is a canonical isomorphism $$G/(N \cap G) \simeq GN/N.$$

This is the content of the [Second Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem), which is stated on Wikipedia with the roles of $G$ and $S$ interchanged.

Note that the last isomorphism comes from applying the first isomorphism theorem to the canonical map $$G \to S/N,$$ $$g \mapsto gN.$$ The image is precisely $GN/N$, and the kernel is precisely $N \cap G$.

Comment: @downvoter Why... ?

Comment: @Chill2Macht Fair point, I guess I missed the "subset" part of the question. From memory, I believe that's directly what the second or third isomorphism theorem is about (both of which are just corollaries of the first isomorphism theorem). I'll probably write something about that tonight or tomorrow, unless you decide you want to do it.

Comment: This answer is very good -- I hope that the OP also appreciates it. I never really understood the significance or usefulness of the second isomorphism theorem before (I thought it was just a piece of trivia to memorize with no useful interpretation) -- a lot of things about basic algebra make more sense to me now than they did before.

Comment: @Chill2Macht Glad to have helped!