# Semigroup epimorphism that is not a quotient by a subsemigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

It is not hard to see that if we have a semigroup epimorphism $\varphi\colon S\to T$, where $S$ is a group, then $T$ must be a group, and it is actually the quotient by the kernel, i.e. the set of $g\in S$ such that $\varphi(g)=\varphi(e)$

The natural argument for this does not seem to work if $S$ is merely a monoid. Namely, $\varphi$ is still constant on the cosets of the "kernel", but there seems to be no obvious reason for this to be an equivalent condition.

Are there some (natural?) examples when this is not true?
In particular, is it possible for a (two-sided?) cancellative $S$? If not, what if $S$ is not a monoid (but merely a semigroup)?

Comment: The right definition of a kernel in the monoid setting is not a monoid, but a category. See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2075013) for more details.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin" Yeah, I was aware that it is not a proper notion of kernel, hence the scare quotes.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: The other question seems interesting though, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very simple example.  Let $S=\mathbb{N}$ and let $T=\{0,\infty\}$ with addition defined the obvious way.  Then there is a homomorphism $\varphi:S\to T$ which sends $0$ to $0$ and every positive number to $\infty$.  The kernel of $\varphi$ is trivial, but $\varphi$ is doing a lot more than just modding out the trivial submonoid!

For an example where both monoids are cancellative, let $S=\mathbb{N}^2$ and $T=\mathbb{N}$, and let $\varphi:S\to T$ be defined by $\varphi(a,b)=a+b$.  Once again, the kernel of $\varphi$ is trivial but it is not the quotient by the trivial submonoid.