# Let $N$ be a finite subgroup of G. Show that $ gNg^-1 \subseteq N$ iff $gNg^-1 = N$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

This question has already been answered here: [Prove that $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$ iff $gNg^{-1} = N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994562/prove-that-gng-1-subseteq-n-iff-gng-1-n)

I was wondering whether the following proof is also acceptable and if not what is wrong with it. Suppose that $gNg^-1 \subset N$ but there exist $n_1$ s.t $n_1 \in N$ but $n_1 \notin gNg^-1$. Since $gNg^-1 = \{gng^-1 | n \in N\}$ we know that $\exists \ a \in gNg^-1$ s.t $ a = gn_1g^-1$, by group cancellation laws we have $n_1 = gag^-1$, since $a \in N$ we have that $n_1 \in gNg^-1$ since $n_1$ is arbitrary we have that $gNg^-1 = N$

Comment: RGR?  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what RGR means but unless it means "abelian group" (in which case the statement is quite trivial) then

> by group cancellation laws we have $n_1=gag^{-1}$

is incorrect. The correct equality is

$$n_1 = g^{-1}ag$$

so you can only deduce that $n_1\in g^{-1}Ng$ not $n_1\in gNg^{-1}$.

---

Finitness of the group is essential here. But you haven't used it in your proof. Let me give you an example that the original statement **does not** hold for infinite groups.

Let $\mathbb{F}_2 = <a, b>$ be a free group in 2 generators. Consider

$$h_n := a^{n}ba^{-n}$$
$$H_n := (h_n)$$

So $H_n$ is a subgroup generated by $h_n$. Now put

$$W_k := (H_k, H_{k+1}, H_{k+2}, \ldots)$$

So it's a subgroup generated by an infinite sequence of subgroups. Note that obviously

$$W_{k+1} \subseteq W_{k}$$

What is not trivial (but nevertheless true) is that this inclusion is proper, i.e. $W_{k+1} \neq W_{k}$. And since

$$aH_na^{-1}=H_{n+1}$$

then

$$aW_ka^{-1}=W_{k+1}$$

So concluding

$$aW_ka^{-1} \subset W_{k}$$
but
$$aW_ka^{-1} \neq W_{k}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was a really silly mistake to make on my part.

Comment: I was wondering how is $aH_na^{-1} = H_{n+1}$ since for e.g $a(a^{2n}b^2a^{-2})a^{-1} \  \not= (a^{n+1}ba^{-n-1}) ^2 $

Comment: @JayK That's because for a generator you have $a(a^nba^{-n})a^{-1} = a^{n+1}ba^{-(n+1)}$, i.e. conjugation maps generator of $H_n$ to a generator of $H_{n+1}$. Elements of the form $a^{2n}b^2a^{-2}$ do not appear in any $H_n$, I'm not sure where did you get that from. Is that a typo?