# Normalizer is subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my textbook, the definition of normalizer is

> $N_G(A)=\{g\in G \mid gAg^{-1} \subseteq A\}$

Many textbooks use this definition.

> $N_G(A)=\{g\in G \mid gAg^{-1} = A\}$

I know that normalizer is subgroup of $G$.

There is no problem when $A$ is finite. Two things are the same.

But if $A$ is infinite, I know that there exists example such that  $ gAg^{-1}$ is strictly in $A$.

In that case, it can be shown that for $g \in N_G(A)$, $g^{-1}\in N_G(A)$?

Comment: do you mean that there is an example of $gAg^{-1}\subset A$ but $gAg^{-1}\neq A$? which is that?

Comment: The definition in the book wrong. For an example, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862

Comment: It is not clear  exactly what the question is!

Comment: @DerekHolt The question is if normalizer is defined as my textbook, it can be shown that it is subgroup of G. It is hard to show that it contains inverse element.

Comment: It cannot be shown that it is a subgroup of $G$ because it is not always true.