# Can we conclude that $gH=Hg$?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is an infinite group and $H$ is an infinite subgroup of $G$.

Let $g\in G$.

Suppose $\forall h\in H\ \exists h'\in H$ such that $gh=h'g$.

Can we conclude that $gH=Hg$?

What if $G$ and $H$ are of finite orders?

Comment: This corresponds to the definition of a *normal  subgroup*. So, yes $gH=Hg$.

Comment: This occurs in one of the proofs in my textbook, but they only conclude that $gH\subseteq Hg$.

Comment: @Bernard Not if $g$ is a fixed element.

Comment: @arctic term: Oh! I misread. Thought it was for all $g$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a fixed element, all we can conclude is that $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$. This does not necessarily imply $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$ for other elements $x\in G$. Nor does it even mean $gHg^{-1}=H$ since it's possible for the conjugate $gHg^{-1}$ to be a proper subset of $H$. There are some examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup) as well as numerous other examples in links. My favorite is letting $\alpha$ be the automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by the formula $\alpha(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$, forming the semidirect product $\mathbb{Q}\rtimes\langle \alpha\rangle$, then considering the strict containment $\langle 2\rangle \subset \alpha\langle 2\rangle\alpha^{-1}=\langle 1\rangle$.

The conjugation map $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is bijective, so $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$, which means if $H$ is finite then the containment $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ implies $gHg^{-1}=H$.

If $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$, then $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in G$. To see this, replace $g$ with $g^{-1}$ then notice $g^{-1}H(g^{-1})^{-1}\subseteq H$ is equivalent to $H\subseteq gHg^{-1}$, so both containments mean equality.

Comment: This answer ought to be accepted.