# Understanding HNN extensions: intuition, examples, exercises.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, intuition, combinatorial-group-theory

> What is an HNN extension? What would be some elementary, intuitive examples of them and what exercises involving them would you suggest?

The [Wikipedia definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension) is easiest to get to, since neither indexes of Magnus *et al.* nor Johnson's *"Presentation$\color{red}{s}$ of Groups (Old Version)"* indicate where they are.

Here it is for convenience:

> Let $G$ be a group with presentation $G=\langle S\mid R\rangle$, and let $\alpha: H\to K$ be an isomorphism between two subgroups of $G$. Let $t$ be a symbol not in $S$, and define
>
> $$G\ast_\alpha=\langle S, t\mid R, tht^{-1}=\alpha(h)\forall h\in H\rangle.$$
>
> The group $G\ast_\alpha$ is called the *HNN extension of $G$ relative to $\alpha$*. The original group $G$ is called the *base group* for the construction, while the subgroups $H$ and $K$ are the *associated subgroups*. The new generator $t$ is called the *stable letter*.

The definition in Lyndon & Schupp's *"Combinatorial Group Theory"*, despite the concept being mentioned a few times prior to it, is on page 179. It's very similar:

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of $G$ with $\phi: A\to B$ an isomorphism. The *HNN extension of $G$ relative to $A$ and $B$ and $\phi$* is the group
>
> $$G^\ast=\langle G, t\mid t^{-1}at=\phi(a), a\in A\rangle.$$
>
> The group $G$ is called the *base* of $G^\ast$, $t$ is called the *stable letter*, and $A$ and $B$ are called the *associated subgroups*.

The definition in Baumslag's *"Topics in Combinatorial Group Theory"*, page 66, reads

> **Definition 2:** Let $$B=\langle X\mid R\rangle$$ be a group given by a presentation and suppose $U$ and $V$ are subgroups of $B$ equipped with an isomorphism
>
> $$\tau: U\stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow} V.$$
>
> Then we term
>
> $$E=\langle X, t\mid R\cup\{ tut^{-1}=u\tau\}\rangle\quad(\text{where }t\notin X)$$
>
> an *HNN extension of $B$ with stable letter $t$, associated subgroups $U$ and $V$ and associating isomorphism $\tau$*.

These are all well & good. I can see how they are equivalent quite readily.

The definition in Stillwell's *"Classic Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory (Second Edition)"* is on page 286 and is much different. I shan't copy it down, for it's quite lengthy, but, again, I can sort of see what it's getting at. There are three exercises on HNN extensions starting on that page too, now that I've looked at the dreaded topology book, so I'll give them a go now.

If you have anything more to add to help me and others understand this important concept, please do so as a comment or even an answer.

I still don't get the intuition behind'm and I know not of any tangible examples yet.

Please help :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Generally speaking, a math.SE post should have a *specific* question included in the title/body. "Please explain X to me" or "what's the intuition behind X" are not specific questions.

That said, I can explain what I know in a comment: the idea of HNN extensions comes from the question of whether two abstractly isomorphic subgroups must be conjugate. This isn't true, but in the HNN extension $G'$, the isomorphism $\varphi:A\rightarrow B$ is forced to become $\varphi(a)=tat^{-1}$ for some $t$. Thus $B=tAt^{-1}$ in the HNN extension.

Comment: This seems like an eminently reasonable question to me!

Comment: Lyndon and Schupp are better than Magnus, Karrass and Solitar for HNN-extensions. The difference is that Magnus et. al emphasised free products with amalgamation, and only mention HNN-extensions briefly. This is wrong. I met Schupp last year and his claim (which I completely agree with!) is that HNN-extensions are the "stronger" of the two constructions and deserved of more study. His example was the Magnus hierarchy for one-relator groups. However, the point is illustrated amazingly well the proof of the normal form theorem for free products with amalgamation in Lyndon and Schupp. Read it.

Comment: (The proof uses the normal form theorem for HNN-extensions.)

Comment: It's just a way to define a bigger group where $\phi$ is the restriction of an inner automorphism of the bigger group.

Comment: Are you familiar with basic algebraic topology?  Like $\pi_1$ stuff

Comment: I wrote up an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423694/10513) which you might find useful.

Comment: I'm afraid not, @PaulPlummer, but by all means share what you have in mind. Somebody else might benefit. I'll catch up topology-wise someday.

Comment: nLab's entry (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HNN-extension) is similar to @ThomasAndrews comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a few bits and bobs.

1) HNN extensions generalize semidirect products with $\mathbb Z$: Take $A$ to be $G$ and $\phi$ to be an automorphism of $G$. Then, $G\ast_\phi = G\rtimes_\phi \mathbb Z$

2) The inclusion of $G$ into any HNN extension $G\ast_\alpha$ is injective, so we can think of the HNN extension as "adding something" on top of our group.

3) Moreover, HNN extensions make more things conjugate in $G\ast_\alpha$ than were in $G$. This is an interesting property to play with!

4) Some of my favourite examples (some of which are downright strange):

- The Baumslag-Solitar groups $BS(n,m) = \langle a, t \mid ta^nt^{-1} = a^m\rangle$ (which include $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ as $BS(1,1)$ and the Klein bottle group as $BS(1,-1)$).
- Some automorphisms of free groups can be rewritten as HNN extensions over $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$, for example the automorphism $a \mapsto a$ and $b \mapsto ba$ yields the HNN extension (with stable letter $b$!) $F_2\rtimes\mathbb Z = \langle a,b, t \mid tat^{-1} = a, tbt^{-1} = ba\rangle = \langle a, t, b \mid [a,t], btb^{-1} = at\rangle = (\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z)\ast$
- [Thompson's group $F$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) is an HNN extension of itself, despite admitting a finite presentation!