# Finding a subgroup $H$ of $G$ where, for some $a \in G$, $aha^{-1} \in H$ but $a^{-1}ha \notin H$ (for all $h \in H$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I prove the that the statements,

(i) $aha^{-1} \in H$ for each $h \in H$

(ii) $a^{-1}ha \in H$ for each $h \in H$

are not equivalent for any particular $a \in G$? I have been trying to come up with a counterexample but I have been unsuccessful. Evidently I would need to find an infinite group which satisfies this, since inductively,

$ \forall h \in H ( aha^{-1} \in H ) \implies \forall h \in H \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+ (a^n h a^{-n} \in H)$

As was pointed out by user Robert Shore.

Comment: What @bof meant to type was: is $a^{-1}ha\notin G$ a typo for $a^{-1}ha\notin H$?

Comment: I don't believe the statement you're asking a proof for is true in general.  If $\ H\ $ is a finite group, for instance, then it's true that for all $\ a\in G\ $ and $\ h\in H\ $ the double implication
$$
aha^{-1}\in H\iff a^{-1}ha\in H
$$
does hold.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera In fact, $ \forall h \in H (aha^{-1} \in H) \Rightarrow \forall h \in H \forall n \in \Bbb N (a^n h  a^{-n} \in H) $ so you won't find a countexample where $a$ has finite order.

Comment: @bof yes that was a typo, my bad! To clarify, here is precisely the wording:
Prove the that the statements (i) $ aha^{-1} \in H $ for each $h \in H$ and (ii) $ a^{-1}ha \in H $ for each $h \in H$ are not equivalent for any particular $a \in G$. As I understand it, this would have the quantificational form: $\neg \exists a \in G \forall h \in H ( aha^{-1} \in H \iff a^{-1}ha \in H )$

Comment: This question has been asked zillions of times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked many times before. A standard counterxample is
$$H = \{\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&x\\0&1\end{array}\right) : x \in {\mathbb Z}\} < {\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb Q}),\ \ \ a=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to find a duplicate, would you be willing to link one?

Comment: I know, it is often hard to find duplicates, because of the difficulty of searching for mathematical expressions. There is one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/)