# If $H \subseteq xHx^{-1} \, \forall x \in G $ then we have $H=xHx^{-1} \, \forall x \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$.

I want to prove that if

$$H \subseteq xHx^{-1} \, \forall x \in G $$

then we have $$H=xHx^{-1} \, \forall x \in G$$

What I've done:

Let $x \in G$. This implies $x^{-1} \in G$.

So we have $H \subseteq xHx^{-1} \implies Hx 
 \subseteq xH $, and by replacing $x$ with $x^{-1}$ we get

$$H \subseteq x^{-1}Hx \implies xH \subseteq Hx.$$

So we get $xH = Hx \implies xHx^{-1} = H \, \forall x \in G$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Do you know what a normal subgroup is?

Comment: Yes. But I saw a definition that said that $H$ is normal subgroup iff $xHx^{-1} \subseteq H \forall \, x \in G$ and I was curious if this also works for $H \subseteq xHx^{-1}$.

Comment: The argument seems fine to me. Having the arrow from $x$ to $x^{-1}$ is a bit strange; I would just replace the arrow with the word "with".

Comment: I have edited now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a little cleaner to simply replace $x$ with $x^{-1}$ directly in the initial containment: if $H \subset xHx^{-1}$ for all $x$ then
$H \subset x^{-1}Hx$ for all $x$, and the second containment implies $xHx^{-1} \subset H$.  Thus $H = xHx^{-1}$ for all $x$.

**Note**.  If $H \subset xHx^{-1}$ for a *specific* $x$ rather than all $x$, then the previous reasoning breaks down and in fact it need be true that $H = xHx^{-1}$ when $H$ is infinite  (of course it would follow if $H$ is finite). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup) for an example with $xHx^{-1}$ a proper subset of $H$.