# Assume $x,\,y\in G$ and both commute with $[x,\,y]$. Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+,\;(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Assume $x,\,y\in G$ and both commute with $[x,\,y]$. Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+,\;(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$.

$[x,\,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ is the commutator of $x$ and $y$.

I have found that 
\begin{equation}
xy^{-1}xy=y^{-1}xyx\\
yx^{-1}y^{-1}x=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\\
[x,\,y][y,\,x]=1\\
x=[y,\,x]x[x,\,y]\\
y=[y,\,x]y[x,\,y].
\end{equation}
However, I can only prove the special case when $n=2$.

Comment: Hint: Use Induction

Comment: I have thought of that. Can you give more details?

Comment: You need to use these three things with induction: $1:$ $xy=[y,x]xy[x,y]$; $2:$ $[x,y][y,x]=[y,x][x,y]=1$ ;$3:$ $x,y$ don't commute with each other but they commute with $[x,y]$ as well as $[y,x]$

Comment: You can also check out this Question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282590/check-in-detail-that-langle-x-y-mid-xyx-1y-1-rangle-is-a-presentation?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $ab=ba$, then $ab^{-1}=b^{-1}a$. Applying this result to $x,y$ and $[x,y]$, we get that $[y,x]$ also commute with $x$.

For $n=2$,
$$
xyxy=xxy[y,x]y=xxyy[y,x]=x^2y^2[y,x],
$$
as required.

Now suppose that $(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$, then
$$
(xy)^{n+1}=xy(xy)^n=xyx^ny^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\\
=xxy[y,x]x^{n-1}y^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\\
=x^2yx^{n-1}y^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1}.
$$
Now use the fact that $[x,[x,y]]=[y,[x,y]]=e$ repeatedly,
$$
x^2yx^{n-1}y^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1}\\
=x^{1+k}yx^{n-k}y^n[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+k}.
$$
Taking $n=k$, we obtain
$$
(xy)^{n+1}=x^{n+1}y^{n+1}[y,\,x]^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}.
$$
By the induction principle, we finish the proof.

Comment: How does $[x, [x,y]] = [y, [x, y]] = e$?

Comment: @Junglemath you are told that in the problem statement

Comment: @DerekHolt How exactly do you use $[x, [x, y]] = [y, [x, y]] = e$ repeatedly to obtain the expression Ma Joad obtained? A few lines of explanation would save hours of headaches for readers.

Comment: It's a straightforward induction on $k$ using $yx=xy[y,x]$.